# Does this scenario qualify as a combinatorial optimization problem?

Tags: combinatorics

I’m buying some food, and want the most calories I can get for my money.

I have a budget of $12.00. There are 3 food groups, and I need to pick 2 items from each of those groups. There is also a Dessert group- I have to pick one dessert item. That’s a total of 7 items. You can’t purchase an item more than once.

So here are my items

```
ID  Food        Group                           Calories    Price
1   Banana      Fruit (must pick 2 fruits)      160         $.75
2   Apple Fruit (must pick 2 fruits) 120     $.65
3   Orange      Fruit (must pick 2 fruits)      160         $1.25
4   Sausage Meat (must pick 2 meats) 260         $3.05
5   Bologna     Meat (must pick 2 meats)        230         $1.15
6   Ground Beef Meat (must pick 2 meats) 310     $3.15
7   Salami      Meat (must pick 2 meats)        320         $2.73
8   Carrots Veg (must pick 2 vegetables) 70     $1.80
9   Cucumbers   Veg (must pick 2 vegetables)    90          $2.10
10  Bell Pepper Veg (must pick 2 vegetables) 110     $1.35
11  Cake        Dessert (must pick 1 dessert)   350         $2.28
12  Pie  Dessert (must pick 1 dessert) 320     $2.90
13  Ice Cream   Dessert (must pick 1 dessert)   380         $1.86
```

What's a simple equation for solving this problem?

Many thanks

Comment: Seems like [knapsack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) with more constraints!

Comment: Sure, it qualifies as a combinatorial optimization problem.  It is desirable to include the problem statement in the body of the Question as well as mentioning it in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an Integer Program.

Let $c_{i}$ be the calories of item $i$ and $p_{i}$ be the price of item $i$. We let $x_{i} \in \{0, 1\}$ indicate whether item $i$ was bought. So we seek to solve:

$\max \sum_{i=1}^{13} c_{i}x_{i}$ s.t.

$\sum_{i=1}^{13} p_{i}x_{i} \leq 12$ (the budget constraint)

$\sum_{i=1}^{3} x_{i} = 2$ (pick two fruits)

$\sum_{i=4}^{7} x_{i} = 2$ (pick two meats)

$\sum_{i=8}^{10} x_{i} = 2$ (pick two vegetables)

$\sum_{i=11}^{13} x_{i} = 1$ (pick one desert)

You can use a dynamic programming algorithm to solve the knapsack problem, or you can try to use an Integer Programming formulation and apply an LP relaxation directly, a cutting plane algorithm, or a branch-and-bound algorithm. I provided the IP formulation above.

Comment: Many thanks. Am I likely to get a different answer if I were to reorder the categories? (for example: meats first, vegetables second and fruits third)

Comment: One more thing- does this look like the right path to do this in Matlab? http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/mixed-integer-linear-programming-basics.html

Many thanks again

Comment: You can label the terms as desired; just be consistent in your labeling. You can also evaluate the constraints in any desired order, as they all apply. I'm not a MATLAB guy. It looks like the right track, that being said.

Comment: Got it- thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)